# Google Maps API RefererNotAllowedError

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have created an Google key for use with the Google Maps JavaScript API.

Every thing works until I add to the credential under 
*Accept requests from these HTTP referrers*

I added the referrer in this format: `*.example.com/*` Per the placeholder on the Credentials page.

Then the  API stops working and throws this error in the js console:

```
Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError 

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: http://example.com/test/
```

The call in the scripts tag on the site:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***********
```

So it seems to be telling me I need to specify the exact url in the referer list.

But I thought the purpose of using the `*` wildcard was so the whole site would allow usage.

Is it really necessary to specify every single location on your website that will use the Map API ?

Comment: Are you sure `*.example.com/*` (all sub-domains of `example.com`) matches `example.com/test/`?  I wouldn't think it would.  Try authorizing `example.com/*`.

Comment: I just tried it without the dot: `*example.com/*`  And it seems to be working. Not sure why their example has a dot. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: It has a dot to allow all sub-domains of `example.com`.  You probably don't want to allow all domains that end with your domain (although that is up to you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*.example.com/*` (all sub-domains of example.com) doesn't match `example.com/test/` (it would match `www.example.com` though).

You need to authorize `example.com/*`